# How to view a stored BLOB image in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, node.js

My stack is Oracle DB, Node.js and React web. I have a stored image as Blob in Oracle DB. I want to view this image in a page but failed. I have the object containing the image in the state but can't view it. This is the object containing the image:

```
{
  USER_ID:5,
  USER_IMAGE:{type: 'Buffer', data: Array(153120)
}
```

This is the component:

```
  const { state: editUserId } = useLocation();
  const userId = useUserId();
  const userInitState = {
    userId: null,
    userImage: null,
  };
  const [user, setUser] = useState({ ...userInitState });
  const [profileImage, setProfileImage] = useState();

  const {
    // data: posts = [],
    data: userProfile = [],
    isUsersLoading,
    isUsersSuccess,
    isUsersFetching,
    isUsersError,
    Userserror,
  } = useGetUserAccountQuery(editUserId);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userProfile?.data) {
      const fetchedUser = userProfile?.data;
      setUser({
        userId: fetchedUser.USER_ID,
        userImage: fetchedUser.USER_IMAGE,
      });
      const file = new Blob([fetchedUser?.USER_IMAGE], {
        type: "image/jpeg",
      });
      const fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
      setProfileImage(fileUrl);
    }
  }, [editUserId, userProfile]);

  console.log("UserProfile2 profileImage: ", profileImage); //blob:http://localhost:3000/9e880575-e302-4bc7-bea2-b2ab8f3923cd

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src={profileImage}
        // src={URL.createObjectURL(profileImage)}
        alt="img"
        width={200}
        height={200}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting image JSON data to typed array first (the `data: Array(153120)` property):

```
const file = new Blob([new Uint8Array(fetchedUser.USER_IMAGE.data)], {
  type: "image/jpeg",
});
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224734) to avoid conflict when two people post same answer around same time. I took mine back